# Why does VertexAttribPointer not throw an INVALID_OPERATION with no VBO bound?

Tags: opengl, opengl-3

From the OpenGL 3.3 Core specification, page 344, it says that if nothing is bound to the `ARRAY_BUFFER` target (or no VAO is bound) when `VertexAttribPointer` is called, an `INVALID_OPERATION` occurs. See [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec33.core.pdf).

```
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

glVertexAttribPointer(index, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void *) 0);
// or doing
glVertexAttribPointer(index, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
```

I just tried this and no `INVALID_OPERATION` occurs, it simply seems to ignore the statement.

Is this a driver issue or a misunderstanding on my part?

If this is intentional, what is a use case for having no buffer bound in an OpenGL Core context whilst calling this function? Resetting the state or is this simply undefined behavior?

*Please note that I'm not asking about what the function itself does, what any of the arguments are for, and simply just wondering why there is no error.*

Comment: If you don't call glBindBufferat all, does it raise an error? The spec contradicts itself: There's no such error condition at VertexAttribPointer section (page 29). Also be aware that the error likely araises later, when you call any `glDraw-x`command.

Answer (score 1):

> See [here](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec33.core.pdf)

I did. And it says:

> An `INVALID_OPERATION` error is generated under any of the following conditions:
>
> ...
>
> - any of the `*Pointer` commands specifying the location and organization of
>     vertex array data are called while zero is bound to the `ARRAY_BUFFER`
>     buffer object binding point (see section 2.9.6), and the *pointer* argument is
>     not `NULL`

If you are referring some text in appendix E, the appendices of the OpenGL specifications are not *normative text*. That is, they don't actually define behavior; they're just notes for reader convenience. Appendix E explains in layman's language what was removed from core; the actual normative text describes explicitly the behavior of the core profile of OpenGL.

Comment: Didn't know that it was just supplementary text, thanks. In a compat context, does `VertexAttribPointer` know to use client memory based on whether a VAO is bound or not? No VAO -> interpret as client memory address and with VAO -> interpret as offset into bound VBO? Thus I can mix together old calls with modern calls by unbinding any VAO?